Fourier transform confusion about convolution theorem
If a function is given by some non-zero $f(x)$ within an interval $a<x<b$, its FT could be found directly by taking the integral. Alternatively, the function can be considered as the product of $g(x)H(x)$ where $H(x) = 1$ for $a<x<b$ and $0$ elsewhere, and $g(x)$ equals $f(x)$ within the interval. Then the FT is given by the convolution of the FT's of $g$ and $H$.
Since $g$ could vary arbitrarily outside of the interval (assuming it tends to $0$), how can this result be consistent? Does the convolution theorem hold?
This question arose during my study of the discrete Fourier transform, where it's assumed that the sampled signal repeats periodically beyond the measured interval.

If you're looking at the restricted Fourier transform applied only to that interval, then the answer is that both $g$ and $H$ would both be restricted to that interval, where $g \equiv f$ and $H \equiv 1$, so their behaviour outside of that interval is completely ignored. And that's fine, because the Fourier transform as you noted does not distinguish between functions based on what happens outside that interval.
If you're looking at the Fourier transform as applied to the whole real line, then the answer is that the step function $H$'s contribution to the convolution will be such that it will cancel out all of the parts of $g$ outside of the interval such that it doesn't matter what $g$ does as long as it matches $f$ in the interval.

"the step function H's contribution to the convolution will be such that it will cancel out all of the parts of g outside of the interval" - proof?

I mean the proof is that the convolution theorem works - if you have $g_1$ and $g_2$ that agree on the interval $(a, b)$ then you will get $g_1 H = g_2 H$ and so $\mathcal{g_1 H} = \mathcal{g_2 H}$. If you actually wanted to see it working, you can pick specific functions and work through the transforms to see what happens.

OK it seemed completely counterintuitive since the FT of $g$ could vary significantly.
